# Moving the mouse with Protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to move the mouse in Protractor, ultimately so that I can click on a Flash button at a certain position. I therefore can't use the element locator, as it's Flash.

I've tried simply moving the mouse with the following:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 50, y: 50}).perform();
browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 250, y: 250}).perform();
```

And I don't see the mouse moving at all in either Chrome or Firefox. I'm using Protractor version 2.1.0.

How can I make the mouse move in Protractor?